# Access Context context from library

Tags: java, android, api

I'm trying to get [this api](https://github.com/igdb/api-android-java) wrapper for android to work.

one of the provided sample methods is:

```
APIWrapper wrapper = new APIWrapper(context, "YOUR_API_KEY");
Parameters params = new Parameters()
    .addSearch("searchQuery")
    .addFields("*")
    .addOrder("published_at:desc");

wrapper.search(APIWrapper.Endpoint.GAMES, params, new onSuccessCallback(){
    @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONArray result) {
            // Do something with resulting JSONArray
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(VolleyError error) {
            // Do something on error
        }
});
```

I imported Context context, but
the problem is that "context" seems to be null no matter what.

How do I get Context context to work correctly?

EDIT: 
Context context=this; worked.

Though when I want to call the same method from another class . Like this:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        test2 method = new test2();
        method.dostuff4();   // call from other class
```

Context is null again?

Comment: in your activity: do this

Context context=this;

Comment: show your code where you are passing context to it

Comment: If it's an activity, use `context = ActivityName.this` in the scope of `onCreate()`, if it's a fragment, use `context = getContext()` in the scope of `onCreate()`.

Comment: You have to initialize your context from context which you can passing from other activity

Comment: Context context=this; worked.

When I want to call the same method from another class . Like this :
        test2 method = new test2();
        method.dostuff4();  

Context is null again ?

Comment: Medy you need to learn about oop concepts first

Comment: Is there smth wrong with the method call ? Iam beginner yes , cant see the problem .

Comment: Can you be more specific pls ? @ Shararti KAKA

Comment: @Medy! one thing you can do is! like this

send that Context you grabbed in the class! while calling the new Class Object by making a constructor in the other class that accepts a context in params

Context context = this;

NewClass obj = new NewClass(context);

and in NewClass there should be a constructor like

globely declare a context Variable first like
Context context
public NewClass(Context context){
this.context  = context;
}

Comment: for starters lets just call it! injecting values into the constructors :-) verrrrrry basic oop

Answer (score 1):

here check this out! its simple injection! but it will do the job for you!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
      private Context context;

   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = this;
    Test2 method = new Test2(context);
    method.dostuff4();   // call from other class

}
```

// and here should be the structure of the Test2 class

```
public class Test2 {
 Context context;
 public Test2(Context context){
   this.context = context;
 }

 public void dostuff4(){
 //here now you can use the context in it
 }
```

}

Comment: Thx. I just found that same answer ;) . Context was a little confusing.  Think I get it now.

Comment: its good to know that it helped. keep on hitting hard! and keep questioning!

Answer (score 0):

What confused me was the context.

I had to pass it along for it to work. 
Problem solved

https://itekblog.com/android-context-in-non-activity-class/